# How to validate using yup to check string min length, max length and allow empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

```
firstName: yup
    .string()
    .test(
        'len',
        'can be empty or with string at least 2 characters and not more than 10',
        (val) => val != undefined && (val.length == 0 || (val.length >= 2 && val.length <= 10) )
    )
```

in this case length min 2 and max 10 works, but when is empty is marked with error i tried with `val.length == 0`

Comment: I guess if you want to allow the value to be empty (0) remove val.length ==0 from code.

Comment: add required() after string, will fix the issue

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan it mus to allow empty

Comment: Could it be that `val` becomes `undefined` if no text is entered?

Comment: @PeterB yeah, that was the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by separate undefined check

```
  firstName: yup
            .string()
            .test(
                'len',
                'can be empty or with string at least 2 characters and not more than 10',
                (val) => {
                    if (val == undefined) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return  ((val.length == 0 || (val.length >= 2 && val.length <= 10)))
                }
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Hello you can do it like this

```js
const yup = require("yup");
const firstName = "";

const schema = yup
  .string()
  .test(
    "len",
    "can be empty or with string at least 2 characters and not more than 10",
    (val) => {
      if (val === undefined) {
        return true;
      }
      return val.length === 0 || (val.length >= 2 && val.length <= 10);
    }
  );

schema
  .validate(firstName)
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Global Function,

```
export const minLengthValidation = (value: string | undefined, limit: number | undefined = 3) => {
  if (value && value.length < limit) {
    return false
  }

  return true
}
```

Invoked the function,

```
  nick_name: yup
    .string()
    .max(50, 'Nickname must be less than 50 characters!')
    .test('min-length', 'Nickname must be greater than  3 characters!', value => minLengthValidation(value))
    .required('Nickname is required.'),
```